# set sorting order as ascending in search event of datatables

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am using datatables plugin to display the data by default data is displaying in descending order but i want whenever i will go to search then the searched data should be show in ascending order.

here is my code. But it gives in error "Maximum call stack size exceeded".

```js
var dTable = $('.MemberListTable').DataTable({
                "paging": true,
                "bSortable": true,
                "lengthChange": true,
                "bRetrieve": true,
                "bProcessing": true,
                "bDestroy": true,
                "searching": true,
                "ordering": true,
                "info": true,
                "autoWidth": true,
                // "responsive": true,
                "aLengthMenu": [[25, 50, 75], [25, 50, 75]]
            });
            
            dTable.on('search.dt', function (e) {
                dTable.order([6, 'asc']);
                dTable.draw();
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing above will cause a problem since the draw event causes Datatables to also perform searches.  So, its an infinite loop.  You can use the below event for the default search input to search and change the column order.

```
$('.dataTables_filter input')
   .off()
   .on('keyup', function() {
      table.order( [ 6, 'asc' ] )
      table.search( this.value ).draw();
   });
```

Comment: Can you please give me an idea for if i am going to apply this for multiple column then what should i do?. I mean it is working only for column 6 if i want to do the same for column then how it would be possible.

Comment: The Datatables [order() API](https://datatables.net/reference/api/order()) docs will provide all the detail.